# What is the largest open set $\frac{1}{\cos z-2i}$ is analytic in?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

This is a very interesting question that I came across and have never solved any question of this sort. How do I find the largest open set on which $\frac{1}{cosz-2i}$ is analytic?
Do I find the set in which $\cos z-2i\neq0$? Any answers will be much appreciated.

Note that $$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recall that
$$
\cos(x+yi)
=
\cosh(y)\cos(x)-i\sinh(y)\sin(x).
$$
If you haven't seen this before, it can be verified with a simple calculation.

So to have $\cos(x+yi)=2i$ we need to have $\cosh(y)\cos(x)=0$.
Since $\cosh(y)>0$ for all $y$, we must have $\cos(x)=0$.
Thus $x=\frac\pi2+\pi n$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$ and therefore $\sin(x)=(-1)^n$.

Now we must have $\sinh(y)=-(-1)^n2$.
Therefore $\cos(x+yi)=2i$ if and only if $x=\frac\pi2+\pi n$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $y=-(-1)^n\operatorname{arsinh}(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ratio of two analytic functions, so it is analytic wherever the denominator is nonzero. (The numerator is constant, so in fact it is analytic *exactly* on the complement of the zero set of the denominator.) So, like you say, it is analytic precisely on the complement of the set where $\cos z - 2 i = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the simple but nice explanation

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. Note that when the numerator and denominator both have a zero at the same point, it's possible that their ratio has no singularity (or rather, a removable singularity, which often by convention we remove): Consider the behavior, e.g., of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ at $z = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for that additional info it was nice to get to know that